# using both :after and :hover

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, pseudo-class, css-content

Is it possible to only display the `:after` pseudo using `:hover`? For example using alternative elements.

```css
#parent{}
#child{display:none;}
#parent:hover >#child{display:block;}
```

As far as I've got with the same method:

```css
#parent{}
#parent:after{content:'hi';display:none;}
#parent:hover  #parent:after{display:block;}
```

Is it possible at all? Or am I fooling myself?

Comment: Have you tried `#parent:hover:after`?

Comment: Did you [try it](http://jsfiddle.net/kUF6v/)?

Comment: @SnareChops I have but I left a space like this `#parent:hover :after` is that my problem? lol

Comment: Yes, remove the space and that should help

Comment: @SnareChops Yea that sorted it *face palm*

Comment: @Beneto `#parent:hover :after` would style the `#parent`'s child element's `:after`, rather than styling the actual `#parent`'s `:after`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine the two:

```css
#parent:hover:after {
    content:'hi';
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vqb8m/).

Comment: Ack, what a [cruel world](http://i.imgur.com/RUXL5vI.png) we live in on our ever lasting quest for the sacred upvotes! ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  Not sure why you didn't try it yourself but it's possible:

```
#parent:hover:after{content:'hi';}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uz3w4/

Answer (score 4):

Yes of course you can :

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ujtyb/)

```
<a href="#">Demo</a>

a:hover:after {
    content: 'blah';
}
```